# iOS: Why the UIBezierPath need long time to drawing?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibezierpath, graphic

*I change the question details because I don't have enough reputation for more links, thanks for understand.*

I've used UIBezierPath to draw rects/lines, but it is slowly for drawing.

1. It's running on a device(iPhone5, iOS 9.2; iPhone5C, iOS8.4);
2. The running time is about 30s, I looked in the Time Profiler in the instruments, all blocked at the UIBezierPath's stroke method;
   [image]
   Below is comes from method [- (void)drawSeriesBar:(CGRect)rect cellData:(CerKlineItem *)data]:
   [image]

Another method:
[image]

Does anyone who knows why the UIBezierPath spends long time? And how to fix it? Thanks for kindly help!

Place code here:

```
//draw line
UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[color setStroke];

CGFloat highHeight = heightForPrice(data.high,rect);
CGPoint highPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect) + CGRectGetWidth(rect) / 2 , CGRectGetMinY(rect) + highHeight);
[path moveToPoint:highPoint];

CGFloat lowHeight = heightForPrice(data.low,rect);
CGPoint lowPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect) + CGRectGetWidth(rect) / 2 , CGRectGetMinY(rect) + lowHeight);
[path addLineToPoint:lowPoint];

[path setLineWidth:1];
[path stroke];
```

Comment: I know this is offtopic, but how did you enable percentage use in Xcode for every method? Thanks:)

Comment: @Fengson that's what you get in the Time Profiler in instruments

Comment: @Fengson Jrturton said is truth

Comment: How are you deciding that your code is slow - are you seeing performance problems? On a device, or on the simulator? When is this drawing being done, and how often? I ask because if you're just going on those percentages you're wasting your time - the numbers have to add up to 100% and the actual drawing parts are always going to take the bulk of the time.

Comment: @jrturton thanks for ur asking, I've tried to add more infos in my question but failed, so add them here: 1. It's running on a device(iPhone5, iOS 9.2; iPhone5C, iOS8.4);
2. The running time is about 30s, I looked in the Time Profiler in the instruments, all blocked at the UIBezierPath's stroke method;

Comment: It looks like you weren't logged in when you tried to edit the question

Comment: Eh, it's OK, please take a look for my change, and I will be glad if you give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your two versions are far from being equivalent:

- the first one contains: move, line, move, line, line, line, as you don't clear the path before adding the second part. Also, the drawing code does not know it's a rectangle, it's using generic polygon fill code
- the second one is just filling a rectangle

You may try replacing the first one with a new path, created using `bezierPathWithRect:`.

Comment: Sorry, the fact is I want to know why the UIBezierPath is slowly to draw. You can see the code above of the red rectangle as the picture, that UIBezierPath is a new path but it still spends long time.

Comment: No, it's not a new path, you're reusing the same path you used to draw a line just above. Also you're comparing filling a polygon with filling a rectangle. Apples and oranges.

Comment: Yes, I mean why UIBezierPath draws the line slowly?